# Capistrano 3 login shell

Tags: shell, capistrano

I already tried using

```
set :default_shell, '/bin/bash --login'
set :shell, '/bin/bash --login'
```

But it does not work, the possible solution would be to include my bin path in /etc/environment but as my installation process is automated through Chef, I cannot do that.

Does anyone know a work-around?

I have already tried putting my bin paths in /etc/profile.d/* and /etc/bash.bashrc but they dont get loaded as capistrano's shell is non-interactive/non-login.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a login shell for Capistrano without

```
`set :pty true`
```

If you simply want to use a login shell to load shell variables or load your path, you can do something similar to this

`set :default_env, { :path => '$PATH:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin' }`